# Laravel: Passing variable from Blade to relationship not working

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to modify a Laravel relationship to return the related case against a question.

My `question` model has the following relationship entry:

```
/**
 * A Question has one Case Detail
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function casedetail( $caseId ) {


    return $this->hasOne( 'App\CaseDetail' )->where( 'test_case_id', $caseId );


}
```

However, trying to access the casedetail from Blade using a variable like this:

```
{{ $Question->casedetail(2) }}
```

Is returning me the following error:

```
"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /home/vagrant/Code/TestBench/resources/views/testcases/category_questions.blade.php)"
```

If I substitute `$caseId` for a specific number and remove the variable request from the method then my query works fine:

```
return $this->hasOne( 'App\CaseDetail' )->where( 'test_case_id', 2 );
```

Result:

```
{"id":1,"test_case_id":2,"question_id":1,"result_type":0,"result":"now what","tester_id":1,"attachment":null,"created_at":"2017-11-30 03:17:42","updated_at":"2017-12-04 06:57:40"}
```

I am trying to retrieve the specific `CaseDetail` from the database that relates to the `question_id` and `test_case_id`. So for each question, give me the related `CaseDetail`:

```
@foreach( $Category->Questions as $Question )

    {{ $Question->casedetail( $TestCase->id ) }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you die and dump the **caseId** `dd($caseId)` variable, and share the result?

Comment: Passing in this: `{{ $Question->casedetail(1) }}` and performing a `dd( $caseId )` gives me a result of 1. Even running a `php artisan tinker` session and passing in `$question->casedetail(2)` will return me 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is correct. In this case, you calling relationship method. Every relationship method returns you object of a collection.

Might be a chance here blade need single property or string to print and method returns collection?

Have you tried like this:
{{ $Question->casedetail(2)->id }}

try to print single property hope it works.